# mosquitto client no longer receiving messages after publishing with QoS=2 (max_inflight_messages=1)

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a mosquitto setup with `max_inflight_messages=1` (for in-order delivery). A client connected to the broker is able to receive messages, but after it publishes a message with `QoS=2`, it no longer receives messages. This behavior was observed after changing the `max_inflight_messages` to 1 from the default value (previously, the client was able to receive messages following the publish)

This was also tested with a `subscribe("/#")`, to ensure it was not a subscribe error. Am I doing something wrong, or is this the expected behavior with `max_inflight_messages=1`?

Thank you for your help.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Having done a quick test, it does look like this might be a bug in mosquitto. If you submit a bug report at http://bugs.launchpad.net/mosquitto then it'll make sure the problem doesn't get forgotten.

In the meantime you can use max_inflight_messages at greater than 1. The in-order delivery is actually quite robust even with max_inflight_messages set>1. It's only likely to be a problem if your client is dropping messages in a particularly erratic manner, which is only likely to happen if your network is disconnecting frequently and the client is doing odd things.

Update: This is fixed for version 1.2.2.